# Jmeter- how can I use CSV file to test multiple login?

Tags: jmeter

I referred to this link https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication but I do not get that option in my webpage.

Also, it is POST not GET

[image]

I get a warning if I click on Parameters

[image]

What should I do here?  I want to be able to sign in using a CSV file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your CSV file looks like:

```
ctvideotest,Paasw0rd
anotherusername,anotherpassword
yetanotherusername,verysecurepassword
etc.
```

And you have CSV Data Set Config setup like:

[image: CSV Example Config]

It is ok to inline CSV-derived variables right into body like:

```
{"userDetails":{"Username":"${username}","Password":"${password}"}}
```

Or if you're confused with "Body Data" representation it is absolutely ok to have it as a "Value" of first parameter like:

[image: HTTP Request Body Data]

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) article for more details on parametrization of your test using .csv sources.

I believe you'll also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json` elsewise your API tests may fail.